# How to restrict the Operation method call in wcf if it fails in IParameterInspector BeforeCall method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I using IParameterInspector BeforeCall method to validate the user for the current session and if the validation fails it will throw the exception and has to return.
I am able to validate it and throwing the exception and I can see it in AfterCall correlationState parameter, but still it is executing the wcf method which I was calling from client.

Is there is any way to restrict that method call to not hit the wcf method in the IParameterInspector BeforeCall method itself.

my code :

```
public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            if (UserAuthenticToken.IsValidUser())
                return null;
            else
            {                    
                return new FaultException("User is not authenticated.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should throw faultexception instead of returning it:

```
public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            if (UserAuthenticToken.IsValidUser())
                return null;
            else
            {                    
                throw new FaultException("User is not authenticated.");
            }
        }
```